# Creating a separate virtual interface for a VLAN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-server-2019

I have Server 2019 and I CANNOT use Hyper-V due to SLAT issues (don't judge my budget). I have a teamed interface from the switch with an untagged network and a VLAN. I have some VirtualBox VMs that I believe are not VLAN passthrough capable but does allow me to select a physical interface. I would like to create a virtual interface on the server which would be on the VLAN and point the VM there. Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS are those VMs running?

Comment: Debian 9. (easy to pull VLAN). I am not sure VBox can pass the VLAN to the VM though.